# Why is the function Fill not found? but the rest of the functions on the library yes?

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

Im workingon a P5.js sketch...

Instead of creating objects with a constructor function, and then using the new keyword.

I want to use a factory function.

It seems to work fine, and renders correclty when using for example this code:

```
 stroke(255,0,0)
 ellipse(speed, 10, 10, 10)
```

But at the moment i try to use `fill(255)`, i get an error saying fill is not a function?

How is it possible that only this function from p5 is not being recognized but others yes?

Here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/giorgiomartini/pen/VVKMKg?editors=0011

Code:

```
function setup () {
  createCanvas(300,500)
  background(3)
  bola = createCircle(circleOpts)
}

const circleOpts = {
  fill: 255,
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  maxRadius: 10,
}

const createCircle = ({fill = 255, x = 10, y = 10, maxRadius = 20}) => {
 let speed = 0
 return {
   display() {
     noStroke()
     background(2)
     stroke(255,0,0)
     // if you remove this next line it works!
     fill(255)
     ellipse(speed, 10, 30, 30)
   }
 }
} 

let bola

function draw () {
   bola.display()
}
```

Comment: `fill = 255` in the parameter list defines it as a number, not a function. It probably *shadows* the function with the same name. So just use a different name for either of the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a variable name conflict: `fill` is a local variable that is created in the function parameter list of `createCircle`. This local variable *shadows* the function name you probably defined in the global scope. And this local variable is indeed not a function (but a number).

You can resolve this with a name change: either change the name of the function `fill` or the name of the local variable `fill`. If you go for the latter option, it could look like this:

```
const circleOpts = {
  fillColor: 255,   // <-------- changed name
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  maxRadius: 10,
}

const createCircle = ({fillColor = 255, x = 10, y = 10, maxRadius = 20}) => {
//                     ^^^^^^^^^
```

... etc.